# Chrome - Still getting "refused to load script due to CSP" even after using "unsafe-inline"

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension

This is for a class project that is due very soon, so I am OK with the unsafe-inline (since people won't actually be using our app).

I keep getting [these errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVkvZ.jpg)
and have tried to find solutions here and elsewhere.

This is in my manifest.json file

```
{
 "name": "Getting Started Example",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Build an Extension",
 "permissions": ["activeTab", "declarativeContent", "storage"],
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'unsafe-inline' http://* 
  https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'unsafe-inline' http://*"}
 "background": {
 "scripts": ["background.js"],
 "persistent": false
},
```

I initialize Firebase using the code from the Firebase site in my options.html

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.0.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
    var config = {stuff from website};
    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  </script>
```

I have also tried putting this in my options.js file without the script tags, but then I get "firebase is not defined"

How can I stop getting this error? I thought I was giving it all the permissions, but I still keep getting the same error.

The lines that the error points to, in my options.html, are:

LINE 1

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

LINE 13 is just < script > on a single line...

Comment: I have installed firebase using a tutorial and it seemed to work ok, but the errors still persist.

Comment: Chrome Extensions does not support inline js or css. YOu must move all inline js in js file like `options.js`.  Regarding  "firebase is not defined": The `firebase.js`  must be included first to `options.js`